# Move command from another directory

Tags: move

I need to move a file from another directory.

Suppose you are in this directory:  `/home/CurDic1`

And my file is located in this directory: `/usr/CurDic2`

I need to write someting like this (I just made it up):

```
/usr/CurDic2:>cd /home/CurDic1 | mv file1.txt /home/CurDic1/SubDic1
```

Comment: So ... what language do you want to do that in?

Answer (score 0):

```
mv path_to_source_file path_to_destination_file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a full path to your move command. In your particular case, it will be :

```
mv /usr/CurDic2/file1.txt .
```

It is important to know that `.` is the current directory.

If you want to move to `/home/CurDic1/SubDic1`, you can do :

```
mv /usr/CurDic2/file1.txt /home/CurDic1/SubDic1/
```

Concerning your made up example, `|` is known as a "pipe" and it is used to redirect the output from the left command to the input of the right column. For example `cat file.txt | less` while redirect the content of file.txt to the less command which is used to scroll in long textual datas.

However you can do

```
cd /home/CurDic1; mv file1.txt /home/CurDic1/SubDic1
```

the `;` is a command separator, it means that the first command will be executed and then the next one. You can chain many commands like this : `cmd1; cmd2; cmd3; etc`